# Why use react-redux and not just redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

A top-level App component subscribes to a redux store in constructor method:

```
constructor () {
  super()
  this.state = store.getState()
  store.subscribe(() => {
    this.setState(store.getState())
  })
}
```

It passes parts of the state to child components as props. If some child component needs to update state, it just dispatches an action:

```
<button onClick={() => { 
  store.dispatch({type: 'INCREMENT'}) }
}>increment</button>
```

What would be the advantage of using [`react-redux`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) over this setup? In other words, why would I need `react-redux` at all?

Comment: With react-redux, you can connect any of your components to the Store using `connect` function. Without `connect`, you have to do it manually. And, generally, the purpose of any library is to reduce the amount manual work.

Comment: Because any subscription you create in Redux will get invoked on every state change, regardless of whether you need to do work on that state slice or not. `react-redux` allows us to specifiy which parts of the store certain components should subscribe to, and therefore we only "subscribe" to the changes we want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gist of it is separation of concerns - `react-redux` allows for accessing and changing just the parts of the state which the component needs to access and change.

@lux's comment answers my question best, so I'll paste it here (emphasis mine):

> Any subscription you create in Redux will get invoked on every state change, regardless of whether you need to do work on that state slice or not. `react-redux` allows us to specifiy which parts of the store certain components should subscribe to, and therefore **we only "subscribe" to the changes we want**

Comment: This is not true as the same can be done in Redux as well and shouldn't be accepted answer at all.

Answer (score 3):

If your component tree is not very deep, then you're right. The advantage isn't so clear. However most React apps that aren't simple examples will quickly have long trees, especially when composing many components together.

Imagine you have a lineage on a tree that goes

```
App -> HomePage -> BlogContainer -> PostList -> Post -> CustomCard -> Card -> LikeButton
```

and `LikeButton` component needs access to the currently selected post, and would like to dispatch an action to update the like count of that post.

In your setup, every component in between `App` and `LikeButton` needs to pass down that information even if they never make use of it. Using `react-redux`'s `connect` function you can directly connect `LikeButton` to the redux store, and have access to `dispatch`. YMMV, but generally speaking this is a nice pattern to take advantage of.

Comment: Wouldn't you still need to pass data down the Post sub-tree? It's an improvement over the original, but the like button still needs to know something about the post or have a callback to it.

Comment: `PostList` would probably pass a post ID to `Post`, which might pass it in turn to `LikeButton`.  Still, definitely not anything that `App` needs to know about.

Answer (score 3):

A number of reasons.

First, per the [Redux FAQ answer on connecting multiple components](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-multiple-components):

> Emphasizing “one container component at the top” in Redux examples was a mistake. Don't take this as a maxim. Try to keep your presentation components separate. Create container components by connecting them when it's convenient. Whenever you feel like you're duplicating code in parent components to provide data for same kinds of children, time to extract a container. Generally as soon as you feel a parent knows too much about “personal” data or actions of its children, time to extract a container.

In other words, a meaningful app will have *many* connected components at various places in the component tree.

More connected components means it's easier to reason about what a given component is doing.  It declares what data it needs from the state, and what actions it wants to dispatch, and you don't have to go passing props all the way down from the root just to get them to that component.

In addition, having more connected components has been shown to be an overall performance improvement.  The cost of more `mapState` calls has been shown to be outweighed by having fewer components doing wasted re-rendering.

Following on from that: React-Redux has had a *lot* of optimization work put into it (and the upcoming [React-Redux v5](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v5.0.0-rc.1) is a complete internal rewrite with major performance improvements).

In other words, if you're using React with Redux, you ***should*** be using React-Redux and its `connect` function to build your UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via Redux and still avoid updates to all components. Yes, you can condition if your current component should update or not. Here's sample code

```
 class VisibleTodos extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
           this.forceUpdate();
      });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.unsubscribe();
    }


    render(){


        const state = store.getState();

        return(
            <TodoList
              todos = {getVisibleTodos(
                  state.todos,
                state.visibilityFilter
              )}
              onTodoClick = {id => {
                  store.dispatch({
                      type: 'TOGGLE_TODO',
                    id
                })
              }}
            >
            </TodoList>
        )
    }
}
```

The same thing with react-redux library will be done as

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {


return {
    todos: getVisibleTodos(
      state.todos,
      state.visibilityFilter
    )
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onTodoClick: (id) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'TOGGLE_TODO',
        id
      });
    }
  };
};

const { connect } = ReactRedux;
const VisibleTodoList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList);
```

So imagine there are several other components similar to this and in former case, calls to `this.forceUpdate()` and `this.unsubscribe()` will be redundant. Hence, it saves us from manual work.